# connecting to multiple ports using python socketserver

Tags: python, sockets, python-multithreading, tcp, socketserver

Ok, trying to port over some C++ code to python. For this specific case I need to set up a TCP/IP server to accept communication over multiple ports. In the old C++ code multiple instances of casyncsocket are created corresponding to each port.

I would like to do the same thing using python 3. Looking through other examples I attempted to modify one to work. Below I added some extra lines to try to connect to ports 1520 and 1525.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import socketserver
from threading import Thread

class service(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        data = 'dummy'
        print ("Client connected with ", self.client_address)
        while len(data):
            data = self.request.recv(1024)
            self.request.send(data)

        print ("Client exited")
        self.request.close()


class ThreadedTCPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    pass

t = ThreadedTCPServer(('',1520), service)


m = ThreadedTCPServer(('',1525), service)

t.serve_forever()
m.serve_forever()
```

I get errors whenever I run the above. If I take out

```
m = ThreadedTCPServer(('',1525), service)
m.serve_forever()
```

Then it works fine. 
I am a beginner if socket programming and python and didn't have much luck finding examples. Any help is appreciated.

**Updated:**

Well it appears I have found a working solution.

```
import threading
import socketserver


class Datahandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        self.data = self.request.recv(2048)

        if self.data:
            self.request.sendall(self.data)


class ThreadedTCPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    pass


def main():
    global TDC_servers
    global TDC_server_threads

    TDC_servers = []
    TDC_server_threads =[]

    TDC_servers.append(ThreadedTCPServer(('', 1520), Datahandler))
    TDC_servers.append(ThreadedTCPServer(('', 1525), Datahandler))

    for TDC_server in TDC_servers:
        TDC_server_threads.append(threading.Thread(target=TDC_server.serve_forever))

    for TDC_server_thread in TDC_server_threads:
        TDC_server_thread.setDaemon(True)
        TDC_server_thread.start()

    while True:
        continue


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()


    finally:
        print('quitting servers')

        for TDC_server in TDC_servers:
            TDC_server.server_close()
```

Comment: Maybe the Mixin uses a class method, so you try to start another server on the same thread?